# Get notified of incoming Bitcoin transaction, as soon as it broadcasted

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, zero-confirmation

After a few weeks of searching for an answer, I decided to ask here.

I want to accept a Bitcoin payment, to a specific wallet, and immediately, when the user approved the payment, to receive an indication that the payment was made.

The problem is, I don't want to wait until it is verified in a block, which takes around 10 minutes, I need the approval in seconds, not minutes.

How can I receive an indication that a Bitcoin transaction was occured to my wallet, in the last seconds?

Comment: The standard Bitcoin client will show pending transactions as soon as they hit the network.  There is some risk in accepting a zero confirmation transaction.  If this is for a brick and mortar establishment it is not likely that a double spend attack can be performed.  However online I would be more conservative. Particularly if the item being sold is not revocable such as a digital download.

Comment: Related: [How do I accept bitcoin payments at a real world store?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/327/5406)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using the `walletnotify` option in `bitcoin.conf`, you can get a notification any time a transaction occurs on the network that matches a bitcoin address in the wallet. To use this, of course, you'll have to keep Bitcoin-QT or `bitcoind` running at all times.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Once you have the transaction id, you'll have to look up the transaction, either at an online service like blockchain.io or use a [bitcoind json-rpc](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) command to learn more about the transaction and what action you would like to take.

Comment: Is there anyway to get all new transactions? instead of only transactions of a specific address.